# Can not connect to MySql server remotely

Tags: mysql

I can not connect to MySQL server from a remote computer. When I try to connect it gives me the error

> Host '' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

I've edited the MySQL server my.ini file by changing the bind line from #bind = "127.0.0.1"  to bind = *. I've turned off the firewall of the client machine trying to access the server. I also gave full privilege to the user of MySQL database through which I am  trying to connect to the server by using the MySQL grant command, but nothing seems to be working.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Show exactly how the MySQL user is setup especially the host part of the 'user'@'host'

Answer (score 2):

A MySQL user has a "from host" field. This is probably set to some IP and those mismatch, giving you that error.
This field allows for extra security and can be set to any IP/hostname.
If this field is set for the user then you can only login to the MySQL server with that user from the IP/hostname specified.
If you want to test your connection you can just use a wildcard for the "from host" field `%` so that any IP can connect using that user, I wouldn't recommend this in a product environment though.

Comment: To expand on this answer, the way to see where a user can connect from, do a `show grants for <user>` command. You will see the permission being granted to `'<user>'@'<host>'`. You want to make sure that the `<host>` is '%' and not 'localhost'.

Comment: thanks alot it worked. u said using the wildcard % for the host field, for a user is not recommended in a production environment, please why, what are the implication.

Comment: is there any way to specify a range of ip's that should connect to the database through that user?

Comment: Yes, just re-add the user you want with the same password multiple times for different hosts/IP's.

Answer (score 1):

First check if you can connect to port 3306. You can use telnet for this, from your client system execute 
`telnet <server ip> 3306`
You should get connected or asked for a password.

Also you can see if the port is open for outside connection by executing 
`netstat -an` to get the list of open ports and the listening ip.

If that works then try to use a mysql client to connect using `mysql -h <hosst> -u <user> -p <database>`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need to grant privileges to connect to the database, to the user/host that is trying to connect.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html.

Comment: i've done that already and its still not working